# Selecting variable based on DataFrame column name

Tags: python, pandas

I've just gotten started with Python so I am sure this must be pretty straight-forward but I still cannot find the answer myself.

I am trying to apply  a different operation to columns within a DataFrame based on the column name. Here's a very simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

A = 2
B = 4

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2],[3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])
columns = list(df)
```

Now, what I would like to do is use a for loop to iterate over each column and use the column name to figure out which variable to reference. Like this:

```
for item in columns:
    df[item] = df[item] * item
```

I other words I would like column A to be multiplied times 2 and column B by 4. The issue is that I don't know how to "convert" the column name into a variable reference.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is ```df ['A'] =  df['A'] * A``` and ```df ['B'] =  df['B'] * B```.

Comment: I agree for the example provided. However, my real problem is more complex since I have a DataFrame with several columns and I wanted to iterate through the columns and select relevant operations based on the column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionary by all possible columns values and then multiple columns maped by [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
A = 2
B = 4

d = {'A':A, 'B':B}

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2],[3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])

df = df.mul(df.columns.map(d))
print (df)
   A   B
0  2   8
1  6  16
```